# Mongodb transaction if document has multiple copies

Tags: mongodb, database-design, distributed-system, distributed-database

Consider I have a document A in the MongoDB database with multiple copies (as it is a distributed db, partition P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> has same entry A)

Given there is single document transaction in Mongo, if I update A to A<sub>1</sub> , can I be ensured that both the partitions P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> has same copy of data A as A<sub>1</sub> at the same time. So if I query for A<sub>1</sub>, I will be getting the same value from both the partitions ?

If not, what am I not understanding correctly for Mongodb ?

I was going through https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/ and system designing and faced the question.

Comment: I think I don't understand some of the setup of the question to begin with. What is a 'partition' in your context? Is it two members of a replica set or is it two shards in a sharded cluster? If the latter, then A does not exist in both. If the former, then read and write concern become relevant. You can read all about that in the docs you linked [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/#read-concern-write-concern-read-preference)

Comment: I am assuming `partition` to be one of the replication of the many places in mongoldb where data is stored.
Am I wrong in assuming that? Is shard and partition different in a db context ?

Comment: I think you're referring to the first configuration in my previous comment, meaning that  P1 and P2 are two data-bearing members of the same replica set. MongoDB's replication is asynchronous by nature, but acknowledgements to clients regarding writes completing successfully is controlled by write concern. Similarly you can use read concern to configure what data should be eligible for retrieval when a query is issued. The docs cover this in detail, but transactions aren't necessarily required in your situation as far as I can tell